# Intersections {x^2/y+y^2/x=25 and 5-x^2=y}

Tags: quadratics

I did run in to this problem last week in school and it was supposed to be solved with algebra.

> This isn't just two quadratic equations

Solve all intersections

x^2/y+y^2/x=25
5-x^2=y



Spoiler

> I did get this two
>  (25-5x^2+x^3-5x^4-x^6)/(5x-5x^4)=25
>  100-75x^2+x^3+15x^4-x^6=0
>  I did get a difrent sulution on my CAS calkylator
>  (x⁶ - 15x⁴ - x³ + 75x² - 125) / (x³ - 5x) = 25

How do you solve the intersections and check if you missed anyone

The X values the solution should be at

> {x = -2.19267344038, x = 0.7772329487424, x = 2.19261654432, x = 3.893011723522}

Answer (score 0):

Substituting the second equation into the first one:
$$\dfrac{x^2}{5-x^2}+\dfrac{(5-x^2)}{x}=25$$
$$\dfrac{x^3+(5-x^2)^2}{5x-x^3}=25$$
Gives:
$$x=-2.192...\vee x=0.198...\vee x=2.192...$$
So the three solutions are:
$$x=-2.192...,y=0.195...$$ 
$$x=0.198...,y=4.960...$$
$$x=2.192...,y=0.195...$$

Comment: Check it on a graph

Comment: Or just, fill it in (which is what I did) and it works. you don't get exactly $25$, but the answers aren't completely accuracte (the three dots mean the decimals keep going on)

Comment: you missed one - http://imgur.com/a/Lbizw

Comment: >! It is probebly two non real also